# How Java's BigInteger sign-magnitude works

Tags: reverse, bit, biginteger

Consider the following code:

```
int i = 1;
System.out.println("1 binary: " + Long.toBinaryString(i));
long ri = Long.reverse(i);
System.out.println("1 reverse bit decimal: " + ri);
System.out.println("1 reverse bit binary: "+ Long.toBinaryString(ri));
BigInteger bil = new BigInteger(1, Longs.toByteArray(ri));
System.out.println("1 Sign-Magnitude BigInteger toString: " + bil.toString());
```

The output is:

```
1 binary: 1
1 reverse bit decimal: -9223372036854775808
1 reverse bit binary: 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1 Sign-Magnitude BigInteger toString: 9223372036854775808
```

Can anyone help to explain why the value of "1 Sign-Magnitude BigInteger toString:" is 9223372036854775808 (2^63)?

Comment: Plase read up about one's complement, two's complement -- which Java uses for simple types like int and long -- and sign-magnitude, which BigInteger uses. You seem to be confusing *reverting*, *inverting* and *negating*. In two's complement, negating means inverting and adding one. In one's complement, inverting and negating are the same. In sign magnitude, negating means flipping the sign bit. But none of those *revert* (i.e. turn the lowest bit into the highest, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

To get the sign-magnitude of a value, you simply take its absolute value as magnitude and remember the sign in a separate bit (or byte).

The sign-magnitude representation of, say, `722` is simply:

```
sign = 0
magnitude = 722
```

The sign magnitude of `-722` is simply:

```
sign = 1
magnitude = 722
```

That is also what `BigInteger` uses.

Your code **reverses** a value, which means that, say, the 8 bit value `00000001` (1) is changed into `10000000` (128 or 2^7). That is not the same as **inverting**, which turns e.g. `00000001` (1) into `11111110` (254). That is what **one's complement** does. The generally used **two's complement** negates `00000001` (1) into `11111111` (255, i.e. 256 - 1). You should read up about [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement), which takes some understanding. Sign-magnitude is, however, very easy to understand (but not always very practical -- addition, subtraction are different for signed and unsigned, etc. -- and that is why most processors use two's-complement)

So again: sign-magnitude works like this:

```
sign = (n < 0)
magnitude = abs(n)
```